# bootstrap dropdown caret breakes in safari

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I`m trying to do ellipsis on the dropdown from angular ui bootstrap and the caret keeps breaking down either on safari, chrome or firefox. Fixing one will break another.

I've made a plunker with it and while it works in chrome, it will break in safari :(

## Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.21" data-semver="1.2.21" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="testController">
    <div class="btn-red">
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
        <div class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
            <span class="title">
                {{ data ? data : noTitle }}
            </span>
            <span ng-if="data" class="caret"></span></div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## JS

```
var testApp = angular.module("testApp", []);

testApp.controller('testController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'titie';
}]);
```

## CSS

```
div.btn-red {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div.btn-red div.btn-group div.btn-primary {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: #e16a60;
    border: 0px;
}
div.btn-red div.btn-group div.btn-primary span.title {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.btn-red div.btn-group div.btn-primary span.caret {
    height: 100%;
}
div.btn-red div.btn-group ul.dropdown-menu {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
div.btn-red div.btn-group ul.dropdown-menu li {
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 5px;
    float: right;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
div.btn-red div.btn-group ul.dropdown-menu > li: hover {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
div.btn-red div.btn-group ul.dropdown-menu li.current {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #e16a60;
}
div.btn-red div.btn-group ul.dropdown-menu li i {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

You can find the plunker here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ulBVDFl2tWBUOp9bWiF0?p=preview

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix that would be awesome.
Thanks.